# Add devices option missing from iOS Provisioning Profile?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I don't know if this is something to do with the new TestFlight integration or a glitch or what, but I just created a new Distribution Porfile for an iOS app and there is nowhere to add my test devices. Normally there is a list of all my test devices in a scrolling window where indicated, but it's not there on this new profile.  If I go to a different existing distribution profile that was set up months ago, there is a list there of all devices.

I checked the app store docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW28, and you can see in the image for step 4, where the list normally appears.

Anyone else seeing this? Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will not be a device list if you are making a Distribution provisioning profile for the App Store. Make sure you are either creating a Development provisioning profile or you are selecting "Ad Hoc" when creating a Distribution one.

Comment: Thanks. Can the adhoc cert then be used to create an IPA that gets submitted to the app store? My other distribution certs look identical and have devices and I create IPAs with them that I submit to the app store ok.  Is there any way to tell an "Ad Hoc" from an "App Store" cert, apart from the lack of ability to add devices?  (This one even says "0 Devices" in the summary where the others say "X Devices"). Thx again!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, after some experimentation I confirmed that was it. It seems there's no way to tell an "Ad Hoc" from an "App Store" cert, apart from the lack of ability to add devices.  They even say "0 Devices" in the summary where the others say "X Devices"). I was worried I couldn't submit an adhoc signed IPA to the app store, but indeed I can. That must have been what I had done before. Thanks again.

Comment: @mm2001 that's correct. If I was personally designing that page I would have definitely not used "0 Devices" label in that provisioning profile. It's just confusing. :P

Comment: FYI I highly recommend submitting your app using Xcode. It chooses the right provisioning profile when you do and gives you all the appropriate error messages. You don't want to submit something and wait a week to find out something went wrong.